# Duplicate Apache POI jars

Tags: eclipse, apache-poi

I've installed Apache POI in Eclipse following the instructions in https://www.tutorialspoint.com/apache_poi/apache_poi_environment.htm

When I look at my project Build Path->Libraries, I see duplicate entries for -

commons-codec-1.10.jar

commons-logging-1.2.jar

junit-4.12.jar

These all have one jar in each of these folders -

C:\Selenium\selenium-2.53.1\libs

C:\Selenium\selenium-2.53.1\poi-3.15\lib

Looking at the .classpath, the entry for C:\Selenium\selenium-2.53.1\libs 
appears first.

Is there a conflict and if so, which should I remove from the Build Path? Also, which should I add the Javadocs to?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

right click on project... go to properties... go to java build path... click on the jars you want to remove.. there is a option to remove in right side...

then add external jars n find the jars in your system.. and add those jars...

remove all the jars and add them again one time... and copy those jars in lib also...

Comment: Thanks, but are you saying that there should be duplicates?